# Spark framework request.body cant obtain checkbox values

Tags: html, checkbox, spark-java

I'm trying to get a list of checkboxes from a post metho on spark framework like this. I'm using Freemarker template too.

HTML:

```
...
<form class="form-horizonal" name="maCreaIncidencia" action="/maCreaIncidencia" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">

<div class="col-lg-3"><!--CONTENEDOR-->
    <fieldset><legend><h5>Roles Asignados</h5></legend>
        <div class="checkbox" name="rolesAsignados" id="rolesAsignados"> <!--id="asignados">-->
            <#list roles as rol>
                <div class="row" name="asignados" id="asignados">
                    <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="${rol.idRol}" value="${rol.idRol}" style="display:none" onClick="if(this.checked)desmarca(this);"><label for="${rol.idRol}" style="display:none">${rol.idRol} - ${rol.rol}</label>
                </div>
            </#list>
        </div>                          
    </fieldset>
</div>
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active btn-block" type="submit" value="Añade Nueva Incidencia" >
</form>
...
```

And in java code:

```
...
String url = request.body();
...
```

But url value is null. Can show me the way to solve it?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working? Getting one selection from a checkbox is working. But getting the values from multiple checkboxes is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `request.body()` returns request body sent by the client, not a url.

With a simple example like this.

## template (car.ftl)

```
<form action="/" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

## main.java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import spark.ModelAndView;
import spark.template.freemarker.FreeMarkerEngine;

import static spark.Spark.get;
import static spark.Spark.post;

public class Main {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        get("/", (request, response) -> {
            return new ModelAndView(null, "car.ftl");
        }, new FreeMarkerEngine());

        post("/", ((request, response) -> {
            LOG.info("------> " + request.body());

            return new ModelAndView(null, "car.ftl");
        }), new FreeMarkerEngine());

    }
}
```

## Log output

```
2015-10-13 15:34:44,889  INFO [qtp297991908-20 - /] Main: ------> vehicle=Car
```

see full project here: https://github.com/dominicfarr/spark-framework-request-body